# How much resistance should a pull resistor include?

Tags: resistors, pulldown, push-pull

How much pull to ground resistance do I need?
Is the amount you need variable?
How did you figure this out? (Where can I learn too)
Any references I should look to?

So sorry for my large host of questions

How much resistance should a pull down resistor have? Is it one size fits all or do I need larger pull downs for different things.

Cheers!

Comment: related: [Chosing a pulldown resistor](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/45291)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chosing a pulldown resistor](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45291/chosing-a-pulldown-resistor)